# iOS 9 Compatiblity issue

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, ios9

Hi i have developed an app with xcode 6.4 & Swift 1.2. Now the app is live on AppStore, but most of the app users report me an issue that after upgrading their device os to iOS 9 *"myApp"* is not working properly.

is that iOS9 does not support to app developed in xcode 6.4 or something like that.? 
please advice me.
Thanks in advanced

Comment: It would help if you would say what _exactly_ you mean by "not working properly".

Answer (score 2):

The direct answer to your question of "is that iOS9 does not support to app developed in xcode 6.4 or something like that" is, in general, apps written with Xcode 6.4/iOS 8 should work under iOS 9.

Thousands and thousands of existing iOS apps written as far back as iOS 2.0 will generally work under iOS 9.

However, many apps will break under iOS 9. This can be due to bugs in iOS 9 but generally it's due to the apps being written incorrectly.

You've had the last three months to test your Xcode 6.4/iOS 8/Swift 1.2 app with the iOS 9 beta. You should not have just now discovered problems.

You can attempt to fix your app with Xcode 6.4 and get it to work under iOS 9 if you don't wish to upgrade to Xcode 7/Swift 2.0 quite yet (you will need to do so though in the next few months).

Start by seeing why the app is crashing.

Answer (score 2):

There is some very confused stuff here.

You built a version using Xcode 6.4, developed for iOS 8. When a user upgrades their phone to iOS 9, while they have already downloaded your app, the app is supposed to run unchanged.

There is some bug in your application that stops it from working properly on iOS 9. Bugs happen. To fix this, you get a phone running iOS 9, then you use it to test your application, built with Xcode 6.4, still developed for iOS 8. You find out what the problem is and you fix it. You know, the normal process for developers: You find bugs, you fix them.

I recommend that you listen to what maddy said and don't upgrade to Xcode 7 *right now*. Use Xcode 6.4 to make the minimal changes to get your application to work, and once that is accepted on the app store, you download Xcode 7 and upgrade your app.

Answer (score 0):

Although the iOS9 is not supported by xcode 6.4, but it supported app developed in xcode 6.4. May you should test your app for iOS9.

Comment: No, i have not tested app using iOS 9. When i was uploaded that time there is no footprints of iOS 9/xcode 7.

Comment: IOS 9 has lots of changes and plenty of bugs. This is normal. 

It is a normal part of app development for you to check your app still works on a new version of iOS. Often something small breaks. Most apps have small issues that don't take longer than a day to fix.

Answer (score 0):

I have used diawi for making the link from ipa.
I used xcode 6.4 to build.
When user with iOS9 TRYING to install the build.
They not able to install because xcode 6.4 not support iOS 9.
So please use xcode 7 for iOS9.

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

The best way for you is that you download the Xcode 7 and rebuild your app and deal with the building problem.

> One problem I have met these days is that "Some deprecated API removed
>   from iOS9,which make my app crashed!"

For the real example:

[image]

You can check here:https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS90APIDiffs/index.html

The best way for you to check this is that you use Xcode 7 to rebuild it,and then you will find all.